# ansible fact caching in redis

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to get custom facts (**set_fact**) persistent between the playbooks.

*i.e.* `provision something.yaml -> email.yaml`

I have configured the *caching* for redis:

```
fact_caching = redis
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
fact_caching_connection = localhost:6379:0
```

I can see the facts being stored in redis("ansible_facts10.1.0.7):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "ansible_cache_keys"
2) "ansible_factslocalhost"
3) "ansible_facts10.1.0.7"
```

What I can't understand is how do I get a custom fact to another play?

My issue is that if I need to use a **redis lookup** then using fact caching is pointless since I can write the set_facts to redis by myself through a redis task.

Is there a way to do an automatic lookup for a variable in redis cache without using following:

```
- name: query redis for somekey
  debug: msg="{{ lookup('redis_kv', 'redis://localhost:6379,somekey') }} is value in Redis for somekey"
```

At the moment the key in redis for my cached facts will require hard coding of some sort, since it's being named after the IP from hosts file i.e. "ansible_facts**10.1.0.7**"

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `cacheable` option of [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/set_fact_module.html) module:

```
- name: provision
  hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        myfact: something
        cacheable: true
```

This way `myfact=something` will land into redis cache for `myhost` host.

When you run other play

```
- name: check_fact
  hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: myfact
```

You should see `something` fetched from redis.

Keep in mind that `cacheable` option was introduced in Ansible 2.4.

Comment: Ok I see what’s the problem now... my first playbook is already cacheable but if run against different host. Is it possible to access the **set_fact** from different host without complicated redis lookup?

Comment: Please check the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)